# Error dependencias symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony2, composer

Estoy instalando un proyecto Symfony 
al ejecutar composer install me da el siguiente error:

He mirado por hay y suelen recomentdar actualizar la version de symfony pero no no puedo actualizarla. Ademas el proyecto esta funcionando en otros equipos con el mismo composer.json

Esta instalación en concreto la estoy intentando hacer en un linux-mint montado en un disco duro externo como un usb-live con persistencia.

```sh
rick@mint:~/repos/myvitale$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.52
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.50
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.48
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.47
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.46
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.45
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.44
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.43
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.42
```

Este es mi composer.json:

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "twig/twig": "<2.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.12",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.5",
        "twig/extensions": "1.4.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "1.5.2",
        "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.2.2",
        "orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/translation-bundle": "@stable",
```

Agradecería cualquier pista.

El problema me esta dando en usb live con persistencia. No se si esto es determinatne.

Comment: Me han comentado que podría ser por la version de php.
En ambos equipos la version que tengo es :
`PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 (cli)` . Asi que de momento he descartado esa idea...

Comment: Has probado a borrar el bundle del composer.json y luego cargar los vendors? Si eso te funciona, en principio con poner un `composer require `  del paquete debería buscarte la versión que mejor funcione...

Answer (score 1):

El paquete symfony/symfony ya contiene el componente orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle. Por lo tanto, intenta instalar el componente en una sola versione **(2.8.52)** o superior **(5.0.5)**. Esto solía funcionar en versiones anteriores de Composer, pero se corrigió en 1.7.2. Debe eliminar el paquete de orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle  y utilizar el componente en la versión 5.0.5 o eliminar la dependencia de symfony/symfony y requerir todos los componentes explícitamente en la versión que necesita.